# How to show labels in first two rings only in a zoomable sunburst partition with rotated labels?

Tags: d3.js

Provided the following fiddle, how can I modify it to display the rotated labels in the inner two rings only? It's simple enough to show the label based on the depth of the node, but it breaks after zooming. I removed my modification which clamped labels to the first two rings, since it fell apart on zoom, so that the fiddle is a clean slate.

```
 var text = g.append("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")rotate(" + computeTextRotation(d) + ")"; })
      .attr('text-anchor', function (d) { return computeTextRotation(d) > 180 ? "end" : "start"; })
      .attr("dx", "6") // margin
      .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sss4r/g71ydz6g/1/)

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want it to show the top two labels even when zoomed?

```
var text = g.append("text")
  .attr("class", "label") //<-- add class to look up later
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")rotate(" + computeTextRotation(d) + ")"; })
  .attr('text-anchor', function (d) { return computeTextRotation(d) > 180 ? "end" : "start"; })
  .attr("dx", "6") // margin
  .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
  .style('visibility', function(d) { //<-- set it initially
      return (d.depth === 0 || d.depth === 1) ? 'visible' : 'hidden';   
  });

function click(d) {
  d3.selectAll(".label") //<-- find them all
    .style('visibility', function(d2) {
      return (d2.depth === d.depth || d2.depth === d.depth - 1) ? 'visible' : 'hidden';   //<-- set visibility based on selected node
    });

  ...
```

**EDITS FOR COMMENTS**

Since the zoom is shows click + 1 level up, looks like you need to handle the 0 depth as a special case:

```
 function isTextVisible(d, depth){
   if (depth === 0){
     return d.depth === 0 || d.depth === 1;
   } else {
     return d.depth === depth || d.depth === depth - 1;
   }
 }

function click(d) {

  d3.selectAll(".label")
    .style('visibility', function(d2) {
      return isTextVisible(d2, d.depth) ? 'visible' : 'hidden';   
    });  

  ...
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/g71ydz6g/3/).

Comment: Thank you, sir. It mostly works :-) I'm afraid that after zooming in, and then back out, the labels no longer show on the 2nd ring. Perhaps I might accept your answer, and you, or I, or someone else, may follow up with upgrades. The side effects of zooming breaking the constrained labels was part of the original problem I was encountering.

Comment: This is looking very good. Do you know why the "flare" label shows in the center ring when I click on "vis" but not when I click on "util"? Do you know why all the labels show briefly when I click on one of the outer rings to zoom? I've had the browser freeze a few times zooming in and out in that fiddle--may be completely unrelated to your mods. At any rate, many thanks!